# Trace sequence of scripts/commands executed upon ssh

Tags: bash, login, debugging, trace

I am executing `ssh myuser@myserver`.

**Is there any way to trace all actions performed and the names of files being sourced? (similarly as with `bash -x)`**

PS: I executed `bash -x` at the command prompt after `ssh`ing (spawning another Shell), but I do not know if the sequence of actions is the same as when `ssh`ing (see [Where are commands sourced upon ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408101/137608))

Answer (score 1):

use verbouse
To trace a command or a script use -v
ex:

ssh -v myuser@myserver

Comment: Interesting perspective. I had assumed the OP was talking about the files that the remote shell would touch, but looking at your answer it's clear to me that the OP doesn't actually tell us +1